# Why does my tic tac toe minimax algorithm utilizing a 1d representation of a tic tac toe board and allowing for play of both sides not work?

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, tic-tac-toe, minimax

I wrote a python program utilizing the minimax algorithm to play tic tac toe. The board is represented by a 1d array. The player is able to play as either side. The program recursively generates all of the legal boards and checks for a winner alternating between minimizing and maximizing every turn. For some reason the algorithm never generates a winning board.

At first I assumed it was related to the algorithm not minimizing and maximizing for the right side but I checked and I don't see any reason the code wouldn't work

```
import random

def getOtherPlayer(letter):
    if letter == "X":
        return "O"
    else:
        return "X"


def getWinner(board):
    for i in range(3):
        # Check rows
        if board[i*3] == board[i*3+1] == board[i*3+2] != "":
            return board[i*3]
        # Check columns
        if board[i] == board[i+3] == board[i+6] != "":
            return board[i]
    # Check diagonals
    if board[0] == board[4] == board[8] != "":
        return board[0]
    if board[2] == board[4] == board[6] != "":
        return board[2]
    # Check for tie
    if "" not in board:
        return "Tie"
    # No winner yet
    return None

def test():
    board = ['X', '', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O']
    print(getScore(board, 'X', False))

def getAvailableMoves(board):
    return [i for i in range(len(board)) if board[i] == ""]


def getScore(board, letter, isMaximizing):
    winner = getWinner(board)
    if winner == letter and isMaximizing:
        print('win')
        return 1  # current player wins
    elif winner == letter and isMaximizing is False:
        print('lose')
        return -1
    else:
        print(board)
        print(letter)
        print(isMaximizing)
        print('tie')
        return 0  # tie (no winner)


def minimax(board, letter, player):
    if player == 0:
        if letter == "X":
            bestScore = float('inf')
            isMaximizing = False
        else:
            bestScore = float('-inf')
            isMaximizing = True
    if player == 1:
        if letter == "O":
            bestScore = float('inf')
            isMaximizing = False
        else:
            bestScore = float('-inf')
            isMaximizing = True
    winner = getWinner(board)
    if winner is not None:
        print("terminal")
        return getScore(board, letter, isMaximizing)
    availableMoves = getAvailableMoves(board)
    if isMaximizing:
        for move in availableMoves:
            board[move] = letter
            score = minimax(board, getOtherPlayer(letter), player)
            board[move] = ""
            bestScore = max(score, bestScore)
    else:
        for move in availableMoves:
            board[move] = letter
            print(board)
            score = minimax(board, getOtherPlayer(letter), player)
            board[move] = ""
            bestScore = min(score, bestScore)
    return bestScore




def findBestMove(board, startingLetter, player):
    availableMoves = getAvailableMoves(board)
    bestMove = None
    bestScore = -9999
    for move in availableMoves:
        board[move] = startingLetter
        score = minimax(board, getOtherPlayer(startingLetter), player)
        board[move] = ""
        if score > bestScore:
            bestScore = score
            bestMove = move
    return bestMove


def printBoard(board):
    print()
    for i in range(3):
        print(board[i * 3:i * 3 + 3])

# Main Code
test()
letter = 'X'
board = [""] * 9
player = random.choice([0, 1])
print("You are playing as", player)
while True:
    printBoard(board)
    winner = getWinner(board)
    if winner is not None:
        if winner == "Tie":
            print("Tie")
        else:
            print("Winner:", winner)
        break
    if player == 0:
        if letter == "O":
            move = findBestMove(board, letter, player)
            print("Computer played move", move)
            board[move] = letter
        else:
            move = int(input("Enter move (0-8): "))
            while board[move] != "":
                move = int(input("Invalid move. Enter move (0-8): "))
            board[move] = letter
    elif player == 1:
        if letter == "X":
            move = findBestMove(board, letter, player)
            print("Computer played move", move)
            board[move] = letter
        else:
            move = int(input("Enter move (0-8): "))
            while board[move] != "":
                move = int(input("Invalid move. Enter move (0-8): "))
            board[move] = letter
    letter = getOtherPlayer(letter)
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I feel this is too specific to be of general use. It should probably be moved to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ (but I cannot vote for moving it there).

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in your `getScore` function.

It only returns a non-zero value when the winner is `letter`, but not when the winner is the other player. Yet that is the situation you will have: if there is a win, it will have been played by the player that moved **last**, while in your calls to `getScore`, `letter` is actually the player who is *next* to play. As a consequence, `getScore` will return 0 even when the game has been won.

Here is a suggested correction of that function:

```
def getScore(board, letter, isMaximizing):
    winner = getWinner(board)
    # When the game is not over yet, or it is a tie, then return 0
    if not winner or winner == 'Tie':
        return 0
    # When we get here, we know the game has been won.
    # Return 1  when `letter` is the winner and is maximizing, or
    #           when `letter` is the loser  and is minimizing
    # Return -1 when `letter` is the loser  and is maximizing, or
    #           when `letter` is the winner and is minimizing
    # In short: if the expression `winner == letter` has the same boolean value as
    #           `isMaximizing` return 1, else return -1
    return 1 if (winner == letter) == isMaximizing else -1
```

A small remark: When analysing your code I found it quite confusing that you used a variable `player` which determines whether the human player plays with "X" and "O", but the variable is a number (0 or 1). You can avoid some code repetition by using "X" and "O" also for the `player` value.

Also, why not make "X" always the maximizing player, no matter if it is the human or non-human player? Sure, you'd need a bit more care in the `findBestMove` function, but all the rest would become simpler.